# do_shortcode() won't return PHP Array

Tags: shortcode

I have made a shortcode `[get_clients]` which is supposed to return an array of all the clients when called via `do_shortcode('[get_clients]')`. But all it returns is a string 'Array' only. Why?

Comment: because the shortcode returns array you can't echo it, foreach() loop can help ^^

Comment: do_shortcode() returns only string by the way [look](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: `do_shortcode()` returns only string values.

Comment: Shortcodes are intended to be used to *print* something on the screen. This is the reason why they return always a string: only a string can be *printed*. If you trying to use a shortcode to return an array, you are _doing_it_wrong. Add in question the relevant code you are using, and probably someone can suggest you a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns a string. So you should join the elements of the array to make a string.

From the Codex:

> **Function Reference/do shortcode**
>
> Return Values
>
> *(string)*
>
> Content with shortcodes replaced by the output from the shortcode's handler(s).

Comment: I can serialize an array before returning and then unserialize it.

Comment: Please read @G. M.'s comment as well: "Shortcodes are intended to be used to print something on the screen."